# Does a python method exist to play deezer song?

Tags: python, api, deezer

I'd like to know if it's possible to have a deezer player under a Python application.
I'm working on a XBMC Deezer plugin in order to have deezer integrated in XBMC software (a famous media center software).
XBMC plugin are written in Python and as you already know there is no SDK for this language.
The only way I found to do this is to open a web page which integrates a Deezer player in it. My web page and my Python plugin communicate by an Ajax communication.
I just wanted to know if it's possible to receive an audio stream by the Deezer api.
For example does it exist a method like this http://api.deezer.com/play?id=xxxx&time=xxxx ?
where id is the ID of a song and time is the moment where of the begining of the stream. This method will return a PCM stream or any else audio format stream of x seconds.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to look at the Deezer API on their site to understand what you can and can't do and then come back if you've found a method and are unable to make the code work in Python. I'd also recommend posting in the XBMC python script forum.

Comment: In fact I posted my request here because the link is on the Deezer API documentation website. I sent an email to the Deezer team and I'm waiting for their answer.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to play a stream from Deezer is to use one of the existing SDKs as we don't provide streams directly from the API (for encryption issues). Since we don't have any SDK for Python, is there any way you could make the Javascript one work?

Comment: I use the JavaScript SDK in a dedicated web page but I wanted to avoid that. Indeed, the goal of my project is to use deezer under XBMC on an embedded system like the raspberry pi.On those kind of system a web browser is not necessary installed. Moreover it isn't very clean to have a webpage launched in background. I'll have a look to see if it's possible to run a JavaScript code in python program but without web page I think it's useless. Thanks for your answer.